# Kivy ScreenManager: App stopped running after trying to add 2nd Window

Tags: switch-statement, kivy, window

I was building an app for my thesis and it worked so far quite well while using only one window. Now I was trying to add other windows for e.g. instructions. I was following the documentation for screen Manager and some examples for apps and tried to add my 2nd window alike. But somehow it fails to identifiy the ScreenManager class in my kv.file. Maybeyou can help out, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

main py: **Peenomat.py**

```
import kivy
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

#additional .kv files used to speciffy layout and functions of peenomat.kv

Builder.load_file('Header.kv')
Builder.load_file('Statusbar.kv')
Builder.load_file('Inputparameters.kv')
Builder.load_file('Outputparameters.kv')

pm = Builder.load_file('peenomat.kv')


#Layout
"""
class Peenomat(AnchorLayout):
    pass
"""
class Peenomat(Screen):
    pass

class Instruction(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

#App
class PeenomatApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return pm

if __name__=="__main__":

    PeenomatApp().run()
```

and  the minimalized .kv file
**peenomat.kv**:

```
WindowManager:
    Peenomat:
    Instruction:

<Peenomat>
    name: "peenomat"

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
                           
            Header:
                id: 
                size_hint: 


            InputParameters:
                id:
                size_hint: 

            StatusBar:
                id:
                size_hint: 
              
            OutputParameters:
                id:_
                size_hint: 

<Instruction>:
    name: "instruction"

    Button:
        text: "Verstanden!"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "main"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

So like I said the App worked before adding the Screen and ScreenManager classes and I'm getting the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/schum/Dokumente/TUD/Masterthesis/Peenomat.py", line 21, in <module>
     pm = Builder.load_file('peenomat.kv')
   File "C:\Users\schum\Dokumente\TUD\Masterthesis\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\schum\Dokumente\TUD\Masterthesis\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 399, in load_string
     widget = Factory.get(parser.root.name)(__no_builder=True)
   File "C:\Users\schum\Dokumente\TUD\Masterthesis\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 131, in __getattr__
     raise FactoryException('Unknown class <%s>' % name)
 kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <WindowManager>
```

eventhough they got the same name. Hope you can help me out!

Comment: I added the arrow brackets to `<WindowManager>`, eventhough most of the examples i found online don't do so. This changed my error to:`kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution by using an implementation of the ScreenManager in the py file. I switched this with the  `class WindowManager(ScreenManager)` class:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Peenomat(name='peenomat'))
sm.add_widget(Instruction(name='instruction'))
```

and therefore added to my builder:

```
class PeenomatApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm
```

I fully deleted the 3 lines with the WindowManager class out of my kv.file. Now it works perfectly fine